# What can i conclude about SalePrice (dependent variable) between independent variables in correlation matrix python?

Tags: machine-learning, correlation, python, dataset, matrix

I'm a beginner with Kaggle House Price dataset to predict Sale Price, just doing data exploration to find out the correlations between the attributes and Sale Price (target variable).

**I came up with a saleprice correlation matrix and have trouble on drawing proper conclusions about each independent attributes with saleprice?**

```
# saleprice correlation matrix
corrmat = df.corr()
corr_num = 15 
cols_corr = corrmat.nlargest(corr_num, 'SalePrice')['SalePrice'].index
corr_mat_sales = np.corrcoef(df[cols_corr].values.T)

sns.set(font_scale=1.25)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(24, 8))
hm = sns.heatmap(corr_mat_sales, cbar=True, cmap='PiYG', annot=True, square=True, 
                 fmt='.2f', annot_kws={'size': 11}, yticklabels=cols_corr.values, 
                 xticklabels=cols_corr.values)

fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.93, right=0.80)
fig.suptitle('SalePrice Correlation Matrix', 
              fontsize=14, 
              fontweight='bold')
```

[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfiMc.jpg)

**And is this matrix able to prove that attributes (OverallQual to YearBuilt) are highly correlated to Saleprice and are important factors to work on for later stage of building model to predict saleprice? Thank you.**

Comment: First of all, welcome to the CV community, and +1 cause you have done some reasonable work. Your assessment is correct that highly correlated variables can be useful predictors. That said, this is not necessary and we should not focus exclusively at them. In many cases they might be spurious correlations  in a sample with little to no predictive power.

Comment: @usεr11852 what would you suggest me to do next?

Comment: Start building some models, interpreter what they do and assess their performance. :)